# How to view package Full Description (commentary section) inside Emacs

Tags: package, package-repositories, documentation, help, undo-tree-mode

I'm looking for a way to visualize *inside Emacs* the **Full Description** of a 
package as shown in [Elpa](https://elpa.gnu.org/) index page.

For example the `undo-tree` package has a nice and comprehensive *help
page/description* embedded in its source code which is fully shown in its
[**Elpa page**](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/undo-tree.html) but the only way
I found to see it inside Emacs is opening its source code.

There's some way to see this full description inside Emacs?

What I know so far:

- It turns out that the section visualized in Elpa *Full Description* is named
  ***Commentary:*** , right below the ***Copyright*** section, both inside the
  source code's preamble. So one way to solve this question is by looking for
  the tools that can extract the source code's preamble and print the commentary
  section.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`M-x finder-commentary RET <library-name> RET` extracts that section and presents it in a separate buffer for reading.  There is also `M-x finder-by-keyword` for discovering libraries this way.

Comment: This function is defined inside the library "finder.el" whose author is none other than Eric S. Raymond, the famous hacker and author of the book "The Cathedral and Bazaar". It's very exciting to know that today we can use tools developed by legends like him and Richard Stallman. Thank you @wasamasa

Answer (score 4):

> I'm looking for a way to visualize inside Emacs the Full Description of a package as shown in Elpa index page.

You're looking for `describe-package`.